# Support new measurement unit to use in android layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, percentage

As far as I know, different measurement units can be used for width, height, padding in android xml layouts. I know that dp is the best to use but I would like to define two new measurement units called "wp" (width percentage) and "hp" (height percentage). I would like to express width, height, padding using this unit. A button with a width of 50wp would be large as half of the screen width. I would like to redefine the point where dp, px are interpreted and introduce this new measurement units. How can I accomplish this? What should I modify?

Comment: AFAIK, you would need to modify the build tools and probably some of the framework classes, the latter of which would go into your own ROM mod to be installed on your phone.

Comment: The best would be if I could simply inherit from a class and do this. I heard from a friend that inheriting from (for example) LinearLayout and overriding inflate and bindViews could do the trick but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Sizing children of a `LinearLayout` by percentage is handled by `android:layout_weight` on the children and `android:weightSum` on the `LinearLayout`. That does not involve creating "two new measurement units" and it does not involve the screen width or height (unless the `LinearLayout` happens to fill the screen width or height).

Comment: I understand but having new measurement units would allow you to use those also for padding. And then, consider this case: I have Button hosted in a horizontal LinearLayout, setting a weightSum for LinearLayout to 100 and Button weight to 50, will not make the button half the screen size, you need also additional fake views.

Comment: "having new measurement units would allow you to use those also for padding" -- sure. However, please re-read my initial comment. While Android is extensible in many areas, it is not readily extensible in the area of of units of measure.